# Laravel loading two models into one list

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-pagination, laravel-paginate

I have 3 models:
User - have many Comments
Article - belongs to User
Comment - belongs to User, Article
In user profile I would like to show all paginated actions of given user. 
What is best and most effective way to do it?

Comment: what is "all paginated actions"?

Comment: By actions I've meant both comments and articles added by user, and paginated - returned in Paginator class with both Comment and Article classes In it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('comments', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('articles', 'users.id', '=', 'articles.user_id')
        ->paginatuse(30);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user= new User::find(1)
->with('comments')
->with('articles')
->get();
```

You might not need the get() , am not sure